# deserialize UUID in spring 4.x

Tags: java, spring, jackson-databind

I was trying to use UUID as one of request param. this results in exception, NoSuchMethodException: java.util.UUID
Steps taken:

- Using UUID as param type results in exception
- So I used String param, accept uuid as string value
- Use UUID.fromString() method to get UUID
  and then use it in code as shown below
- However I noticed there is **UUIDDeserializer** class already in jackson-databind-2.5.5 jar
- Similar issue is observed for java8 LocalDate class which doesnt have public default constructor which can resolved using json mixins but UUID has deserializer unlike LocalDate

How can I make spring create UUID from string automatically and get UUID object instead of having to extend StdDeserializer manually? Is there any annotation may be?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUserByID(String id) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id);  // explicit conversion
        return usersManager.getUserByID(uuid);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUserByID(UUID id) {
        return usersManager.getUserByID(id);
    }
```

Comment: We can't tell without your code. It works fine for me.

Comment: I'm trying to read your mind. Wait...I'm still trying.